# How to identity if an ARM template with VM resource type is for Windows or Linux?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I want to write an [Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/azure-policy-introduction) that applies to ALL Linux VMs.

In the policy, how do I identify if the ARM Template to which the policy will apply is for a Windows VM (where policy should not be applied) or a Linux VM (where policy should be)?

There does not seem to be an OS field in the ARM Template. [LinuxConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines) and [WindowsConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines) are optional, and so may be missing from the template. There are different [offers for Linux and Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage), but there are too many of them, and more added periodically. So, not sure how to target ALL Linux offers.

Answer (score 2):

huh? why does it say msft on your nickname if you ask such questions? the template got windowsconfiguration or linuxConfiguration properties in the osProfile property. you can use that to distinguish

Comment: windowsConfiguration and linuxConfiguration properties are optional. [This](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/apache2-on-ubuntu-vm/azuredeploy.json) is a Linux VM template and [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/visual-studio-vstsbuildagent-vm/azuredeploy.json) is a Windows VM template. Neither have any of these properties.

Comment: in that case you can only filter by image\offer\publisher

Comment: Please read my original question. It already says there lot of offers, and more added periodically. How does one know which is for Windows vs Linux without manually reading them all?

Comment: (plus one) Just for calling a guy who claims to work for Microsoft.  LOL.